# Refer to List item

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to refer to a ordered list's item number purely in HTML/CSS, so that it updates when the items number updates.

ie. Have the number `4` in the first paragraph below auto update to the number of `Log into your account`, given the list below is an HTML Ordered List (`<ol>`)

```
If you already have a user account skip to step 4
1.  Create user Account
2.  Enter you personal information
3.  Click 'Create account'
4.  Log into your account
5.  Do account things...
```

Becomes the following, without having to manually update the first paragraph

```
If you already have a user account skip to step 5
1.  Create user Account
2.  Select your account type
3.  Enter you personal information
4.  Click 'Create account'
5.  Log into your account
6.  Do account things...
```

Comment: No...you need Javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you'll need javascript or a backend logic.

Comment: As an example with Jquery to give you an idea https://jsfiddle.net/nxs09b8b/

Comment: Thanks for the help but its for an internal wiki page where any modules or substitution templates are disabled. So I'm limited to just HTML and CSS

Comment: @coffeecop my answer help? :)

Comment: @JacobGray while it doesn't work in a wiki like i'd hoped, it does work in an html page as my question asked, so I've marked it as the answer. thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* do it with just CSS, but it takes a hacky solution, with [surprisingly good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters).

Basically, the idea is to use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) to count the number of items to the list item you want(marked with a class):

```
<div class="numbered-stuff">
  <p>
    If you want the important stuff, skip to step
  </p>
  <ol>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li class="important">Important Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

In this case, we have the 5th item marked with our class, so we need to increment the counter for every item before it:

```
ol {
  counter-reset: stuff;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: stuff;
}

ol li.important:after{
  content:counter(stuff);
}
```

Quiet simple, right? Now we just need to position the `after` element beside the text. Putting it all together(With a little bit of style, because ugly UI's suck):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
 body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  background: #efefef;
}
.numbered-stuff {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
p {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
ol {
  counter-reset: stuff;
}
ol li {
  counter-increment: stuff;
}
ol li.important:after {
  content: counter(stuff);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: #009688;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="numbered-stuff">
  <p>
    If you want the important stuff, skip to step
  </p>
  <ol>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li class="important">Important Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Of course, you can change the html how you want, but the concept stays the same

Comment: Downvoters care to comment? If you see something wrong with my answer, please let me know, so it can be fixed.